# Preserving state of removed components

Tags: reactjs

I see this patterns a lot when needing to add or remove a component when rendering based on some state (either in props or state).  Such as a tabbed UI, or an expand/collapse widget.

```
render: function() {
  if (this.state.show) {
    var showRender = <Show />;
  } else {
    var showRender = <Hidden />;
  }

  return {showRender};
}
```

However, the problem is each time `this.state.show` changes, a new Show or Hidden is created.  The old state that might have existed in the previous instance of Show or some deep sub-component of Show is re-initialized.

Moving state into the parent isn't practical when the state may exist in multiple components and sub-components.

The other solution I can think of is to put the `"display: none"` style on the component I want to hide.  But if I apply this pattern everywhere, it feels expensive to create all of the UI even if it isn't seen.

Adding the `key="someValue"` prop works as long as the component is just being moved and not completely removed.

Are there any other patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State is for ephemeral data.  If you need to persist this, manage it outside of the components, and use event emitters to allow the component to listen to changes and request changes be made.  The component binds it to state in getInitialState and the event listener.  This is okay, because it's just a local view of the data.  It's still kept safe externally.

A more formal version of this is Flux, which Gaurav mentioned.  Sometimes simple event emitters are sufficient, and sometimes you really need the dispatcher, stores, and actions.

Comment: I agree. Though Flux is that ultimate architectural pattern for React-like components, a similar effect can be had by using other simpler patterns – the crux being managing the data (or "model") outside of components and passing them around via Events instead of components directly. In fact I'm currently stuck with such a compromise pattern because I didn't adopt Flux in the beginning, and refactoring is a big risk at this stage. I think it's worth mentioning that too in my answer and leave it for people to decide what suits them best.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I think it helps me understand some ideas more clearly.  The React component state is ephemeral.  Pulling the state out of the component and into an external Store (in flux) or some other model is a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) architecture was recommended to deal with exactly this kind of dilemma. It frees up your components from the headache of passing around unmanageable amount of props by introducing the concepts of Stores and Dispatchers. Here's a list of tutorials on the subject: https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react#flux-tutorials

Edit:

I hadn't adopted Flux from the beginning for one of my rather complex apps, and now it's gonna be a big refactor to implement it (along with other improvements). As a stop gap, I started using an in-memory Message Bus pattern for new components. Mine is a custom implementation, but you could use a library like [PostalJs](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js). In fact somebody is also attempting a [PostalJs mixin for React](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.react), which might be worth exploring. The idea is for components to publish messages to the Bus to announce actions, which can be consumed by interested components by subscribing via the same bus. The main difference from Flux is: there's no formal "Store", and the Message Bus is a glorified dispatcher. I avoided mentioning this earlier because it's a compromise for me in my current app, and Flux is a safer approach also because of the huge community involvement. Thanks to @FakeRainBrigand for encouraging me to share this other idea too.

Comment: how does this fix the issue given by OP?

Comment: @JeremyD, if i understood correctly, the OP asked for alternate patterns for communicating between components, that are possibly better maintainable. That's what I tried to address. If there's any other specific question I did not address, please help me figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I didn't really understand the question. I thought he was wondering how to avoid the if/else cases when having to choose between components and what should be the way to go. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Flux does solve the problem, as FakeRainBrigand describes below.  Using Flux to pull the state out of the React component....  The if/else isn't the problem.  The adding and removing of the same component and it reseting it's state each time was the problem.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.